# Initializing vector<string> with constant string array crashing

Tags: c++, vector

I've got a class which attempts to initialize a `vector<string>` with 9000 strings and the program is crashing/breaking at the entrypoint to the class's constructor.

This is the only breakpoint info that I can see (indecipherable to me):

```
; Find next lower page and probe
cs20:
        sub     eax, _PAGESIZE_         ; decrease by PAGESIZE
        test    dword ptr [eax],eax     ; probe page. // < breaks here
        jmp     short cs10

_chkstk endp
```

If I instead run the same code with a smaller string array `{"string1", "string2"}`, there is no crash at entry to class constructor.

---

someclass.cpp:

```
#include "someclass.h"

using namespace std;

CSomeClass::CSomeClass()
{   // < crashes/breaks right here or between here and next instruction

    // Crashes
    m_vStrings = {"string1", "string2", ... "string9000"};

    // Works
    m_vStrings = {"string1", "string2"};
}
```

someclass.h:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class CSomeClass    
{
protected:
    vector<string>                      m_vStrings;

public:
    CSomeClass();
};
```

It seems like everything is functionally in order but that I might be running into some kind of, dare I say, Stack Overflow maybe?

Usage:

```
CSomeClass class1; // crashes in here so usage hasn't been tested yet
```

---

This works but is a double allocation which I'd like to avoid if possible:

```
const char* sStrings[] = {"string1", "string2", ... "string9000"};
m_vStrings = vector<string>(sStrings, end(sStrings));
```